# How to fix "command not found: exp"?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, genymotion, expo

I am trying to get expo work with a `react-native` expo project. When I follow the instruction [setting up Genymotion](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/genymotion.html), I got a problem.

I installed "exp" package as instructed

```
   npm install -g exp
```

Seems it was ok, no error.

But when I do,

```
  exp path
```

Showed the following

```
 command not found: exp
```

Searching google did not help. I am using Mac.

The issue happens too often for other tools as well, such as react-native

```
  command not found: react-native
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running it from the terminal?  ```exp``` isn't being found in your path variables.  You can always try adding it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, starting emulator first, then running the app from XDE is worked.
:)
However, the above issue remains, for now, I am ok with it.